# Handle with Error on excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I can't figure out how to handle the error raised in my macro.

Through an `application.Vlookup` I search for a value. The problem is, if that value doesn't exist macro stops.

I tried a `On Error Resume Next` which works fine, but I would like to tell the user the value doesn't exist.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Num As Double
    Dim Cle As Integer
    Dim Dpt As String
    Dim Age As Integer
    Dim Essaidate As String
    Dim CommNaiss As String
    Dim NumOrdre As String
    Dim Reg As String


   'Initialisons la date du jour

    CeJour = Date

    Num = TextBox1.Text

    Cle = 97 - (Num - (Int(Num / 97) * 97))

    If Cle < 10 Then

        Label2.Caption = "0" & Cle
    Else
        Label2.Caption = Cle
    End If

    If Mid(TextBox1.Text, 1, 1) = "1" Then
        Label4.Caption = "Masculin"
    Else
        Label4.Caption = "Féminin"
    End If

    Essaidate = "1" & "/" & Mid(TextBox1, 4, 2) & "/" & "19" & Mid(TextBox1, 2, 2)
    'MsgBox ("La date de naissance (sans le jour) de cette personne est :" & Essaidate)
    Dpt = Application.VLookup(Mid(TextBox1.Text, 6, 2), Range("M1:N96"), 2, False)
    Label6.Caption = Dpt & " (" & Mid(TextBox1.Text, 6, 2) & ")"

    Reg = Application.VLookup(Mid(TextBox1.Text, 6, 2), Range("M1:O96"), 3, False)
    Label15.Caption = Reg

    'On Error Resume Next

     CommNaiss = Application.VLookup(CLng(Mid(TextBox1.Text, 6, 5)), Range("AV1:AW36529"), 2, False) 'That's the line I get an error if value does't exist....
```

Comment: So if there is an error you want to just tell the user and not `Resume Next`?

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please do not post your solution in the body of your post. Feel free to post your answer below among the others, or credit another poster by upvoting  / marking an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a `GoTo ErrorHandler:`, have a `MsgBox`, then resume next.

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Value does not exist"
Resume Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Tim's answer - using an error handler is best but if you want to use on error resume next then you can use IsError:

```
    On Error Resume Next

         CommNaiss = Application.VLookup(CLng(Mid(TextBox1.Text, 6, 5)), Range("AV1:AW36529"), 2, False) 
         if IsError(CommNaiss) then msgbox("value not found")
    On Error Goto 0    ' remember to turn on error resume next off again
```

Answer (score 1):

here follow two possible ways

1) "On Error..." way

```
On Error Resume Next
Dpt = Application.VLookup(Mid(TextBox1.Text, 6, 2), Range("M1:N96"), 2, False)
On Error GoTo 0
If Dpt = "" Then
    MsgBox "Value : " & Mid(TextBox1.Text, 6, 2) & " not found in Range(""M1:N96"")"
Else
    Label6.Caption = Dpt & " (" & Mid(TextBox1.Text, 6, 2) & ")"
End If
```

2) "Find" way

```
Dim found As Range

Set found = Range("M1:M96").Find(What:=Mid(TextBox1.Text, 6, 2), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If found Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Value : " & Mid(TextBox1.Text, 6, 2) & " not found in Range(""M1:N96"")"
Else
    Label6.Caption = Dpt & " (" & Mid(TextBox1.Text, 6, 2) & ")"
End If
```

and the same for `Reg`

Answer (score 0):

This any good? -

```
CommNaiss = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError( _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Mid(TextBox1.Text, 6, 5)) _
        , Range("AV1:AW36529"), 2, False), "Error")
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add `On-Error-GoTo` because the `VLookup` function doesn't throw error but it returns it. Try to declare the variable `Dpt` as `Variant` and check with `IsError` if the `VLookup` returned an error.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Dpt As Variant
    Dpt = Application.VLookup("searched-text", Range("A1:C3"), 2, False)
    If IsError(Dpt) Then
        MsgBox "Error '" & DecodeError(Dpt) & "' occured.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Here an example of function which will decode the error number returned by VLookup to string with description.

```
Private Function DecodeError(ByVal error As Variant) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case CLng(error)
        Case xlErrDiv0
            DecodeError = "#DIV/0!"
        Case xlErrNA
            DecodeError = "#N/A"
        Case xlErrName
            DecodeError = "#NAME?"
        Case xlErrNull
            DecodeError = "#NULL!"
        Case xlErrNum
            DecodeError = "#NUM!"
        Case xlErrRef
            DecodeError = "#REF!"
        Case xlErrValue
            DecodeError = "#VALUE!"
        Case Else
            DecodeError = "Unknown error"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try it as soon as possible. I get no more error at the moment but anyway I need to improve this code forI only begin with macros. I take all your advices. A good way for me to learn more.